# Wikidata prevent fallback languages

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I query some cities with their names .

This works fine. Now when I look at this : https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q729978

I can see there is no spanish name but i get "Mediolanum"

Why do I get there a value? and how can i change it ?

Here my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?label ?population WHERE {
              VALUES (?city) { (wd:Q729978) }    
              ?city rdfs:label ?label
              FILTER(LANG(?label) IN ("de","en","es","fr","it","pl","cs","hr","hu","nl","ru","tr","ro"))
            }
```

The response is

```
{
  "head" : {
    "vars" : [ "city", "label", "population" ]
  },
  "results" : {
    "bindings" : [ {
      "city" : {
        "type" : "uri",
        "value" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q729978"
      },
      "label" : {
        "xml:lang" : "de",
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "Mediolanum"
      }
    }, {
      "city" : {
        "type" : "uri",
        "value" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q729978"
      },
      "label" : {
        "xml:lang" : "en",
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "Mediolanum"
      }
    }, {
      "city" : {
        "type" : "uri",
        "value" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q729978"
      },
      "label" : {
        "xml:lang" : "nl",
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "Mediolanum"
      }
    }, {
      "city" : {
        "type" : "uri",
        "value" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q729978"
      },
      "label" : {
        "xml:lang" : "es",
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "Mediolanum"
      }
    }, {
      "city" : {
        "type" : "uri",
        "value" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q729978"
      },
      "label" : {
        "xml:lang" : "fr",
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "Mediolanum"
      }
    }, {
      "city" : {
        "type" : "uri",
        "value" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q729978"
      },
      "label" : {
        "xml:lang" : "hu",
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "Mediolanum"
      }
    }, {
      "city" : {
        "type" : "uri",
        "value" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q729978"
      },
      "label" : {
        "xml:lang" : "it",
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "Mediolanum"
      }
    }, {
      "city" : {
        "type" : "uri",
        "value" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q729978"
      },
      "label" : {
        "xml:lang" : "hr",
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "Mediolan"
      }
    }, {
      "city" : {
        "type" : "uri",
        "value" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q729978"
      },
      "label" : {
        "xml:lang" : "ru",
        "type" : "literal",
        "value" : "Медиоланум"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that there is no Spanish name? Click on "All entered languages" at this page. See also [1](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Navigating_Wikidata/User_Options) and [2](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wikidata/Notes/Language_fallback).

Comment: My bad i missed the "all entered Languages" field